# How do you correctly use CSS animation delays to create a collapsible HTML container?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to use responsive CSS animation delay to make a accordion type of action happen when a user clicks on a arrow connected to a table without Javascript and only HTML/CSS.

Seen here when you resize the screen to mobile: https://web.archive.org/web/20190523104045/http://responsiveemailpatterns.com/patterns/accordions/full-to-accordion.html

Here's a picture of what I'm trying to do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHOwE.jpg

I commented the CSS block and HTML section with ACCORDION to note where I am trying to code correctly. Whenever I click on the arrow of my box, it acts like an anchor tag and does not collapse the container as shown in the picture. Is there anyway to correct this code without using Javascript or JQuery?

```css
html { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust:none; }
.msofix {mso-table-lspace: -1pt; mso-table-rspace:-1pt}
body{padding:0; margin:0;}   

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 div[class=divSecMobile]{
   display: block !important;
   max-height: none !important;
   overflow: visible !important;
   font-size: inherit !important;
   line-height: 23px !important;
 }

 div[class=divSecDesktop]{
   display:none !important;
 }
  
 .divSecDesktop {
   display:none!important;
 }

 .divSecMobile {
   display:block!important;
   max-height:none!important;
   overflow:visible!important;
   font-size:inherit !important;
   line-height:23px!important;
 } 
 table[class=tblEmail] {
  width: 100% !important;
 }

 table[class=tblContent] {
  width: 100% !important;
 }
 /*Begin Accordion*/
  table[class=pattern] .story td {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
 }
 table[class=pattern] .story td a { display: block; position: relative; }
 table[class=pattern] .story td a:after {
  content: '+';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
 }
 table[class=pattern] #story1:target td {
  max-height: 999px;
  margin: 16px 0;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out;
 }
 /*End of Accordion*/
 td[class=tdPolicyAndDetails]{
  border:2px solid #002663 !important;
 }
}
   .auto-style1 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
   }
```

```html
<table width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="tblEmail" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace: -1pt; mso-table-rspace: -1pt; border-collapse: collapse" >
 
 <!--Begin Accordion -->
 <tr>
  <td style="border-right:2px solid #002663;border-left:2px solid #002663;border-top:2px solid #002663;">
   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="pattern">
    <tr>
     <td width="20%" bgcolor="002663" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:50px;text-align:center;" class="story">
      <a href="#story1"><img src="http://image.email-libertymutual.com/lib/fecc16717d67067e/m/1/Icon_Chevron_Closed_3x.png" width="11" height="17" style="border: none;" /></a>
     </td>
     <td width="80%" style="padding:15px 15px 15px 10px;">
      <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
       <tr>
        <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center; font-size:14px; line-height:20px;color:#002663;text-align:left;white-space:nowrap;">
         <b>Policy #:</b> <font color="#616265">A23-3434-43243-343</font>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center; font-size:14px; line-height:20px;color:#002663; text-align: left;white-space:nowrap;">
         <b>Policy Period:</b> <font color="#616265">02/02/2014 - 02/03/2017</font>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td width="20%" style="color:#ffffff;text-align:center; padding:20px 0px 0px 20px;" align="right" valign="top">
      <img src="http://image.email-libertymutual.com/lib/fecc16717d67067e/m/1/auto_icon_3x.png" width="29" height="21" style="border:none" />
     </td>
     <td width="80%" style="padding:15px 0px 15px 10px;">
      <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
       <tr>
        <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center; font-size:16px; line-height:20px;color:#002663;text-align:left;font-weight:bold;">
         <!--%%[IF Policy1_LOB=="Auto" THEN]%%-->
         Vehicles Insured:
         <!--%%[ELSEIF Policy1_LOB=="Condo" OR Policy1_LOB=="Renters" or Policy1_LOB=="Home" THEN]%%-->
         Home Insured:
         <!--%%[ENDIF]%%-->
        </td>
       </tr>
       <!--%%[IF Policy1_LOB=="Auto" THEN]%%-->
       <tr>
        <td class="tdVehicleInfo" colspan="2" style="padding:20px 0px 10px 0px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:14px; line-height:18px; color:#002663;font-weight:bold;">
         %%Policy1_Vehicle1%%
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="tdVehicleInfo" colspan="2" style="padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:14px; line-height:18px; color:#002663;font-weight:bold;">
         %%Policy1_Vehicle2%%
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="tdVehicleInfo" colspan="2" style="padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:left;font-size:14px; line-height:18px; color:#002663;font-weight:bold;">
         %%Policy1_Vehicle3%%
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="tdVehicleInfo" colspan="2" style="padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:14px; line-height:18px; color:#002663;font-weight:bold;">
         %%Policy1_Vehicle4%%
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="tdVehicleInfo" colspan="2" style="padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:14px; line-height:18px; color:#002663;font-weight:bold;">
         %%Policy1_Vehicle5%%
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="tdVehicleInfo" colspan="2" style="padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:14px; line-height:18px; color:#002663;font-weight:bold;">
         %%Policy1_Vehicle6%%
        </td>
       </tr>
       
      </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <!--%%[IF Policy1_State!="MA" OR Policy1_LOB!="Umbrella" OR Policy1_LOB!="Home" THEN]%%--> 
 <tr>
  <td class="tdIDCards" width="100%" style="padding: 0px 30px 20px 20px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:14px; color:#616265;text-align:left;border-right:2px solid #002663;border-left:2px solid #002663;border-bottom:2px solid #002663;">
  Your ID cards are available online and a paper copy is being mailed to you.
  </td>
 </tr>
 <!--%%[ENDIF]%%-->
<!--End Accordion-->
    
</table><!--tblEmail-->
```

Comment: Consider reducing your code to only what's relevant to your question. Right now it looks like you have a good bit that can be trimmed. Also, consider putting your example in a snippet by clicking the  `[<>]` button when editing your post.

Comment: I couldn't get that to work. So I included a codepen with reduced code.

Comment: I do not understand what you are needing to do. What part of the page in your codepen needs to be expanded/contracted?

Comment: Looks like my image didn't uploaded, here's a imgur: http://imgur.com/a/c0Wtk

Comment: Please consider @santi s comment and clean up your code, there is too much here. Try to create an isolated example you can test stuff out with before plonking it in a full site and hoping for the best. Once you have an isolated piece of code, plonk it in a snippet. Just make it _easier_ for us to help you.

Comment: I can't get the the snippet to work, so I just codepen. I will try reduce it.

Comment: You don't appear to have attached any event handler to the arrow button; it's just an anchor link -- that's probably why it's just acting as an anchor link.

Comment: This is for a Email, so I can't use any javascript. I also added a code snippet.

Comment: You cannot make these fancy animations and interactions in an email.

Comment: It's supported on later versions of IOS and android. See responsive patterns link.

Comment: @somethinghere Actually you can but the e-mail client support is very slim (iOs, android native mail, outlook for mac and apple mail).

Comment: @Sander I know some probably do, but it really isn't worth the effort. People aren't even _expecting_ anything like that :) But yeah, good notice.

Comment: @somethinghere I completely agree!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the template you are trying to use you are missing 1 id on the table cell. Let me explain how this collapsible behaviour works:

In CSS you've got the `:target` selector which is applied when the element is the target of an url. So when you have a `<h1 id="someId">` in the page and you add `#someId` to the url in the browser, you can style the `h1` with `h1:target { color: red; }`.

This technique is used in this collapsible in a nifty way, what happens:

- The anchor tag has a href with: `#story1`
- The parent `<td>` of the anchor has an `id="story1"`
- As soon as you click/tap the plus sign (which is in the anchor), the `<td>` becomes the target
- `td:target` is used to show the part of the content which was hidden

Now looking at your code snippet; the parent  of the anchor is missing the id and never becomes the target of the anchor.